# Is there an equivalent of python help() in C?

Tags: c

If I import a module, or have any class, I can do something like `help(class)` in python to get a description that are premade by the programmer. Is there such a way in C?

Comment: How about `man`, although it doesn't work for arbitrary user-made code. Also, C doesn't have classes.

Comment: This type of functionality is typically provided by IDEs. Information about user-defined functions is provided using DocBlock comments.

Comment: C doesn't have an interactive REPL, where would you type `help(...)`?

Comment: the fact that c is compiled unlike python which is interpreted make sense not to have a help funtion. But I was hoping if there is like a command-line tool to get description of functions. @ggorlen man sounds good how do I use it with it for c functions

Comment: E.g., `man printf`.  Of course, this assumes you're using a Unix-like OS.

Comment: but that wouldnt work for custom made liberaries right?

Comment: @HileamlakYitayew Third-party libraries may provide their own man page.

Comment: @HileamlakYitayew, typically you'd use something like [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to generate documentation from magic comments and / or build your own man pages

Comment: @HileamlakYitayew `help()` in Python doesn't always work usefully for custom-made libraries. Not everyone provides good help docs for their code.

Comment: Yes there is. `Google(class);`

Comment: This is a natural question in the sense that many people coming from something like R or Python might expect a language to provide a built-in link to help and wonder what the closest analog is. I was tempted to downvote the question at first but have decided that it is so natural that it deserves an upvote.

Comment: @Chris I was asking this question so that if such a thing didn't existed I would make a command line tool that would help you get descriptions of functions based on a string that will be put inside the function like python class's have (the _help  = """ help string"""). guess there is no point in making that if ther are already some out there.

Comment: Where would you put this description? If you put in the source code, there are already tools like Doxygen. If you put it in the compiled code, you would clutter and bloat the resulting executable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function that I'm aware of but you can find more information by running `man` for some commands if you run a unix system.

If you can't run man on your OS, you can also check out [devdocs](https://devdocs.io/c/), or the documentation of the library you want to add to your project.

Comment: `man` is a Unix thing, not a C thing. Even on Unix, it won't work for many third-party libraries which one might use in their projects and are not installed system-wide, or simply don't come with man-pages, which are considered somewhat antiquated nowdays.